# Getting a number value from getElementById not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that is supposed to decrease the number inside a span of id "numactions" every time a button is clicked. What I'm missing is how to grab the value of the span id. I'm trying getElementById but that doesn't work.

```
<span id="numactions">5</span>

<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>

<script>
    var clicks = document.getElementById("numactions");

    function clickME() {
        clicks -= 1;
        document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = clicks;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You should use `parseInt(clicks.innerHTML)`

Comment: you are picking the `span` element, not the content, you should grab the content, and use `parseInt()`, like in this [codePen](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/pbYYQX)

Comment: Your codepen worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has two issues.. first, this line:

```
var clicks = document.getElementById("numactions");
```

will grab the HTML element `span` not the **`5`**, to get the content you should use `.textContent` or `.innerHTML`.

Second, using the above you'll get a "string" representation of the content, not a "number", so you'll need to use **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) <sup>(1)</sup>** to get a numeric value.

[**codePen**](http://codepen.io/Mi_Creativity/pen/pbYYQX)

```js
var clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("numactions").textContent, 10);

function clickME() {
  clicks -= 1;
  document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

```html
<span id="numactions">5</span>

<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
```

---

**<sup>(1)</sup>** <sub>It's highly recommended to use *radix*, the `,10)` part of the `parseInt` in the answer, which here means decimal numeral system. Also, while using `parseInt()` you get integers, for float you should use [**`parseFloat()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead.</sub>

Comment: Nice this worked. Most answers below were also correct. Thank you!

Comment: You welcome and I'm glad it helped, and sure enough most of them work so you can upvote them if you want.. enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var clicks = document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML * 1;
function clickME() {
   clicks -= 1;
   document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = clicks;
}
```

Hope useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You needed to parseInt to get the number in the span.

```html
 <span id="numactions">5</span>

    <button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>

    <script>

    var clicks = parseInt(document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML) || 0;

       function clickME() {
           clicks -= 1;
           document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = clicks;
        }
    </script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wh1qfkre/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the innerHTML of numactions in order to get the original count. As it is a string, just parse using parseInt() fn and reduce the counter by one.

```js
   

var clicks = document.getElementById("numactions");

function clickME() {
        var counter = parseInt(clicks.innerHTML)-1;
         document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = counter;
        }
```

```html
<span id="numactions">5</span>

<button type="button" onClick="clickME()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working clickME function without JQuery

```
  function clickME() {
    var content = document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML;
    var intcontent = parseInt(content);
    document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML= intcontent -1;
  }
```

Check the working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/qetaje/edit?html,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified clickMe(), try this it will work

```
function clickME() {
       var val= clicks.innerHTML;
       val -= 1;
       document.getElementById("numactions").innerHTML = val;
    }
```